# $_SESSION based hit counter is not working?

Tags: php

I am trying to make a program, which takes in user's favourite movie name and prints it back. Default favourite is set to `Godfather`.

I have also attached a HIT Counter, based on session variable, but it is not working. It shows ZERO every time the page is loaded. Here is my code:

```
<?php
session_start();

if(!isset($_SESSION['count']))
    $_SESSION['count'] = 0;
else
    $_SESSION['count']++;

if (!isset($_SESSION['movie']))
         $_SESSION['movie'] = "THE GODFATHER";

if(isset($_POST['submit'])) 
    $_SESSION['movie'] = $_REQUEST['moviename'];
?>

<form method='POST' action="index.php">
Please Enter your Favourite Movie
<input type="text" name='moviename' />
<input type="submit" name='submit' value='set movie' />
</form> 

<br /><br />
Your Current Favourite Movie is <?php echo "called ", $_SESSION['movie'] ,"."; ?>
<br /><br />
<?php echo "You Have Viewed this page ", $_SESSION['count'], " times."; ?>
```

You will get `YOU HAVE VIEWED THIS PAGE 0 TIMES`, no matter how many times the page has been loaded.

Comment: Have you any spaces before `<?php` ? and check encoding of your file. If you have UTF-8 with BOM, convert file to UTF-8 without BOM

Comment: I just copied and pasted your code in a file and ran it to my localhost and it works fine. The problem must not be with this code.

Comment: If you close your browser you'll lost your session. When you refresh the page counter still not incrementing?

Comment: Try a var_dump($_SESSION) to see if the problem is with all the session variables or just count var.

Comment: Does `$_SESSION['movie']` store anything?

Comment: I am using UTF without BOM only, and there are no syntax issues. I also checked in phpinfo files, and Sessions are enabled there.

Answer (score 3):

Try `echo session_id();` and make sure it does not change.

If it does change, then you have not configured sessions properly. Check the relevant php.ini settings, in particular make sure the save path exists.

Comment: This. It sounds as though the session isn't being initialised properly on the client side, meaning that the cookie can't be set or whatever else.

Comment: I just Did this, and i notice that my session_id(); is changing... How do I fix that ?

Answer (score 0):

1. Check your encoding, maybe file have UTF **with BOM**, convert file to UTF-8 without BOM
2. Check your file for first lines, maybe `<?php` is no on 1st line